# Will external Storage Folder be deleted when App is updated?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services, android-external-storage

Will a folder like `/Android/data/mypackage/asubfoldername` 
 , which is created like

```
mfolder = this.getExternalFilesDir("asubfoldername").getAbsolutePath();
```

be deleted or its content deleted, **when an app is updated in Google Play ?**

In case of uninstalling it will be deleted I guess, but **what happens when it is updated ?**

Comment: Nope. it would retain the folder as long as the app is installed.

Comment: '/Android/data/mypackage/asubfoldername'. That is an invalid path to begin with. Please have a look at the .getAbsolutePath(); you mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you update your application `/Android/data/mypackage/asubfoldername` it won't delete but on uninstalling application it will be deleted.

check this [link](http://link) for more details